# UWP - No response from InkCanvas

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm building a UWP app for the first time. I'm trying to use an InkCanvas which I've placed on my page but I can't seem to draw on it at all.
I'm using a mouse to try and draw - I don't know if this makes any difference, whether you actually need to use a pen or touch screen.

Can anyone help me with this? What am I doing wrong?

XAML code:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="230" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    </Grid>

    <ListView x:Name="lvItems" ItemsSource="{x:Bind data}" IsItemClickEnabled="False" Margin="60,60,60,0" SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.Header>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="91*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="453*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="210*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Item" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Normal"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Detail" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Normal"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Yes/No" Grid.Column="2" FontWeight="Normal"/>
                <TextBlock Text="N/A" Grid.Column="3" FontWeight="Normal"/>
            </Grid>
        </ListView.Header>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,20,0">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding ItemNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,0" Width="32" ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding ItemDetails}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="400"></TextBlock>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding YesNo}" Margin="20,0,0,0" Width="5"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding NotApplicable}" Margin="20,0,0,0" Width="5"></CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button x:Name="btnOpenFile" Content="Open Data File" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnOpenFile_Click" Height="32" Width="118"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnExportToPDF" Content="Export to PDF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="111"/>


</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to work this out myself.

You need to define which inputs/devices can draw on the canvas.

```
public MainPage()
{
        this.InitializeComponent();

        inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse | Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Pen;
}
```